# ViewModel and ConstraintLayout Beta 2 . incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I just updated the COnstraintLayout version from beta 1 to beta 2, and now I have this compilation error in a ViewModel.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_galery);

        ContactsViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContactsViewModel.class);

        viewModel.getContacts().observe(this, this::updateContactList);
    }
```

The error I have is with the "this"

My build gradle contains the lib like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

If I go back to ConstraintLayout-beta1, there is no compilation problem. Anybody with the same problem?

Comment: Does your activity extend from `AppCompatActivity`, `FragmentActivity`, `Activity`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, AppCompatActivity, the import is import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity. And I repeat, my problem is ONLY when I change the ConstraintLayout from beta1 to ConstraintLayout beta2

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Only to go back to constraint-layout beta 1........I created a bug and everything, but no answer yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import androidx core rc03 as the [LifecycleOwner issue](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.1.0-rc03) seems fixed and exclude it from constraintlayout beta2.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-rc03'
implementation ('androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2') {
    exclude group: "androidx.core.core"
}
```

Or you could wait for a new release of constraintlayout

Comment: Should be able to use implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0-alpha03' instead of 1.1.0-rc03, but this worked for me. Thanks!